# UPDATE one table with SELECT from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables **HOUSES** and **COUNTRIES**

**HOUSES**
**country_code** - example 'ES' for Spain

**COUNTRIES**
**country_code** - example 'ES' for Spain
**houses_total** - example 20 - total houses in 'ES' Spain found in the HOUSES table

I need to count the number of houses in each **HOUSES.country_code** in the **HOUSES** table and update the **COUNTRIES** table with that total in **COUNTRIES.houses_total**

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join with update:

Try below:

```
Update countries as c 
left join  (SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount,country_code  
            FROM HOUSES 
            GROUP BY country_code) as tc 
on c.country_code =tc.country_code  
set c.houses_total =tc.totalcount
```

Comment: @MSB :You should accept answer if it's correct and helped you. It will be use full for others too. check here how to accept and why. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the row for the particular country already exists in `COUNTRIES`:

```sql
UPDATE COUNTRIES SET houses_total =
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HOUSES WHERE HOUSES.country_code = 'ES')
WHERE country_code = 'ES' LIMIT 1;
```

Untested, but it should work.

Comment: I'm think the `limit 1` is not needed... `countries` should be unique on `country_code`

Comment: This is also great and it fitted in with my code on another program - many thanks - 2 solutions in 1 hit that's what I service